# How to receive files from a third party device, can sniff data from TCP listener, but not via post request?

Tags: c#, api, rest, sockets, tcp

I am new in network communication or Rest API. I have to receive some data (xml) and jpg files from a third party software which does not reveal much about the communication. All it says it supposed to send me a post request to my http address(which is http://[My_PC_IP]:873 via post request). I have hosted a rest api post method in this url, which I can can see accepting post request(I sent empty data) Telnend API tester.
[The post method in my tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uplVx.png)

But i am not able to receive any data from that device to my rest api http address via post method.
So i made a tcp lisenter on this port and i see i am getting following data via this port (873).

```html
POST http:\\192.168.1.148:873 HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=boundary
Host: 192.168.1.148
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 553999

--boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data.xml"; filename="data.xml"
Content-Type: text/xml; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Length: 1884

<XYZ version="2.0" xmlns="http://www.qwret.com/ver20/XMLSchema">
<ABC>192.168.1.177</ABC>
.............

</XYZ>

--boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Picture1.jpg"; filename="Picture1.jpg"
Content-Type: image/pjpeg
Content-Length: 5467
Content-ID: Picture

???? JFIF   ............................
```

It seems it is sending post request indeed, but how to get receive this files can somebody please guide me?

Comment: You have a schema.  Use a WebBrowser and go to URL.  Then convert schema to c# classes.  You contract should match the root class of the schema.    It looks like you are receiving a multiple mime results with the first result being the xml and the second being a jpeg.

Comment: It seems they are sending data files data via tcp socket only (not actual post method).. Why the headers are like that..I dont get it. If i cut the response string on the boundary string and save the xml and jpeg file, should it work?

Comment: HTTP is an application layer that uses TCP as the transport layer.  You have an array so maybe the array is an issue.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/code-contracts#visibility